# ReactJS using JSX or Babel

Tags: babeljs, reactjs, jsx

I am new for ReactJS. Should I go with **JSXTransformer or Babel for writing ReactJS** code?

I understand that *ReactJS implementation is not depend on JSXTransformer / babel*. We can use ReactJS without these two too, but still I want about this with respect to ReactJS.

Answer (score 4):

This is opinion based so should probably be closed.

Pretty sure the React team have deprecated the use of the JSX Transformer (outside of in-browser development usage) in favour of Babel. Babel now supports everything that React needs (and more) in a convenient and standard way and should be considered the *preferred* method of JSX transformation.

More information on React tooling can helpfully be found at their [tooling page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Matt Styles is right, it's beeing deprecated:

from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html)

> JSXTransformer is another tool we built specifically for consuming JSX
>   in the browser. It was always intended as a quick way to prototype
>   code before setting up a build process. It would look for 
>   tags with type="text/jsx" and then transform and run. This ran the
>   same code that react-tools ran on the server. Babel ships with a
>   nearly identical tool, which has already been integrated into JS Bin.
>
> We'll be deprecating JSXTransformer, however the current version will
>   still be available from various CDNs and Bower.

However it is **great to learn** the basic of react, focusing on component methods, passing props, etc.. with a easy integration.

But i believe you won't be able to require any node modules, wich will block you soon or later.

To learn React and the node environnement, I suggest you to make a few tutorials, and to test and read the code of simple boilerplates project like these:

[react-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json)

[react-transform-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-boilerplate/blob/master/package.json)